# Add php array in variable

Tags: php

How will I add the PHP array to variable so i can add it to the database as one variable, *e.g.*

```
$personnel = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
```

I tried to use `foreach` then add it to the database but the last value only send to the database

```
foreach ($personnel as $person) {
  $p = $person.", ";
}
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO travel_print (personnel, name, office, division, unit_head, position, date, purpose, venue, reference, date_to, date_from, activity, check_type) VALUES ('$p','$name','$office','$division','$unit_head','$position','$date','$purpose','$venue','$reference','$date_to','$date_from','$activity','$business')");
```

**result:**

[image]

**the result that i need.**

[image]

Comment: `join(",",$personnel)`

Comment: `$p .= $person.", ";`, you lost the `.` in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use implode function:

```
$p = implode(',', $personnel);
```

You can get more info in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use serialize:

```
$args = ['person', 'person', 'person'];
$string = serialize($args);
```

Now you can put $string in database.

Using unserialize() for return array from string.

Or, if you want to save array like this: person, person, person,
You can simple use implode

```
$people = ['fred', 'wilma', 'barney'];
$string = implode(', ', $people);
```